# JSON response cannot extract variables

Tags: json, typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

Brand new to react-native and typescript!
I'm have a bit of trouble extracting JSON response. I was to extract the response and put it into a class as shown below.

Here is the request code

```
    let notifications: INotification[]

    notifications = (await Requests.GET('notification/user/test-user-1', accessToken));
```

Here is the class

```
      export interface INotification {
          id: string;
          senderId: string;
          receiverId: string;
          text: string;
          isSeen: boolean;
          type: string;
          timestamp: string;
      }
```

Here is the Postman response

```
{
    "notifications": [
        {
            "pk": "user-1",
            "sk": "notification1234",
            "entity": "notification",
            "id": "id number",
            "senderId": "test-user-2",
            "receiverId": "test-user-1",
            "text": "Test notifications",
            "isSeen": false,
            "type": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is response from the console

```
  { notifications: 
       [ { pk: 'user#test-user-1',
           sk: 'notification1234',
           entity: 'notification',
           id: 'id number',
           senderId: 'test-user-2',
           receiverId: 'test-user-1',
           text: 'Test notifications',
           isSeen: false,
           type: 2 } ] 
}
```

I want to be able to write out:

```
console.log("TEXT: ",notifications[0].text )
```

And get the response of :  "Text: Test notifications"

Any help welcome!

Comment: Can you edit the question adding what you're currently trying, what's the output of that attempt, and how it differs from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

the data is in an array you need to pass the array first

console.log("TEXT: ", notifications[0].text);

Comment: hi there! thank you for your response. When I run that I get back this:

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'notifications[0].text')